# How can I clear a vector layer features in OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers

I want to clear my vector layer features, I did it before in OpenLayers 2 with destroyFeatures(); command, I research many times but I can't do that in OL4. How can I do that?

My OpenLayers 2 code:

```
    if (self.selectFeatureLayer) { self.selectFeatureLayer.destroyFeatures(); }
    if (self.markerLayer) { self.markerLayer.clearMarkers(); }
    if (self.layerRuler) { self.layerRuler.destroyFeatures(); }
    if (self.measureControls) {
        if (self.measureControls.line.active) {
            self.measureControls.line.deactivate();
            self.measureControls.line.activate();
        }
        if (self.measureControls.polygon.active) {
            self.measureControls.polygon.deactivate();
            self.measureControls.polygon.activate();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`layer.getSource().clear()` function doesn't work properly. You can try `removeFeature(feature)` method of `ol.source.Vector`. I wrote a sample for this issue:

```
 var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  })
});

map.on('click', function(evt) {

    var features = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
    features.forEach((feature) => {
        vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
    });
});
```

[**Sample url**](https://codepen.io/himyata/pen/qXjeOK):  **Click on map to see it.**

I wrote under map on click. You can write whereever you want.

Answer (score 5):

First get the source of your layer, and then call the [clear](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#clear) method to remove all features from the layer:

```
layer.getSource().clear()
```

Comment: I am trying now but I get this error: "Cannot read property 'clear' of null", Could it be because the source is empty?

Comment: Are you sure the layer you are trying this on has a vector source?

Comment: I am sure its type Vector but I am not assign any source yet, for now its empty.